# Как сделать так, чтобы каждый символ (буква) воспринимался, как отдельный

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-3.6

К примеру у меня алфавит из 6 символов (`ABAABA`). Я их пишу в массив, но как сделать, чтобы код сравнил этот алфавит, и писал, какая буквы больше по количеству.

На входе я ввожу число и буквы. К примеру я в входные данные пишу число `4`, и следовательно я должен вести `4` буквы. Потом эти буквы я должен сравнить, и вывести ту, которая самая большая по количеству.

Например: Ввожу `7` и `AABBAAA`, и код должен вывести `A`, так как их больше всего.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Попробуйте переформулировать вопрос, приведите пример кода из которого было бы понятно, что у вас на входе и что вы ожидаете получить на выходе.

Comment: Ок. 
На входе я вожу число и буквы. К примеру я в входные данные пишу  число 4, и следовательно я должен вести 4 буквы. Потом эти буквы я должен сравнить, и вывести ту у которая самая большая по количеству

Например: Вожу 7 и AABBAAA
А код должен вывести A, так как их больше всего

Comment: @VenomSkill исправьте очепятки - `не вожу`  а ввожу. `Вожу 7` - Ввожу 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, для каждой буквы нужно вывести к-во её копий в спике?

```
a = ["C", "A","A","A","B","A","B"] # можно заменить строкой
b = set(a) # ["C", "A","A","A","B","A","B"] ==> {"C", "A", "B"}
c = {}
# для каждой буквы считаем к-во совпадений в списке
for i in b:
    c[i] = a.count(i)

# сортируем словарь по значению (возвращает список кортежей (key, value))
cSorted = sorted(c.items(), key=lambda i: i[1], reverse=True)
print(cSorted)
print(cSorted[0])
# [('A', 4), ('B', 2), ('C', 1)]
# ('A', 4)
```

Comment: Да.

Я вожу число 6, следовательно и 6 символов я должен вывести. Потом должен вывести самое больше по колчеству символ

Comment: Отдерактировал код. Если вопрос решен, тыкните галочку возле ответа

Answer (score 2):

```
text = 'ABAABA'

d = {}

for b in text:
    d[b] = d.get(b, 0) + 1

print(d)
{'A': 4, 'B': 2}
```

Comment: Красивое решение. Вместо применения `.get()` вы могли бы использовать `defaultdict(int)` (со значением `0` для несуществующих ключей): `d = collections.defaultdict(int); for b in text: d[b] += 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Класс `Counter` из стандартного модуля `collections` предназначен для того - *он автоматически подсчитает количество нахождений отдельных символов в строке* (или отдельных элементов в *списке, кортежи, множестве и т.д.):*

```
from collections import Counter

strng = "ABAABA"                  # или даже список ["A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A"]

c = Counter(strng)                # c будет: Counter({'A': 4, 'B': 2})
print(c.most_common(1))           # 1 - только один (первый) из самых частых
```

Вывод:

> ```
> [('A', 4)]
> ```

---

Когда вы хотите вывести только *символ сам*, добавите дважды индекс `[0]` - первый для первого (единичного) элемента *списка парей*, второй для первого элемента *этой пары:*

```
print(c.most_common(1)[0][0])
```

Вывод:

> ```
> A
> ```